# Is a function's derivative continuous on $(a,b)$ if it is injective on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Say a differentiable function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined on an open interval $I$, and there is a closed bounded interval $[a,b] \subseteq I$. If $f'$ is injective on $[a,b]$, is it continuous on $(a,b)$?

Comment: Would you consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ if $x<1$, $2x^2 - 1$ if $x>=1$ to be a counterexample? If not, why not?

Comment: @RickyTensor Personally, I would not, because your $f$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: Of course [a,b] is "interval that is bounded. "

Comment: @stililrise I have edited your post. Please check that it retains your intended meaning.

Comment: @Sambo Yes thank you for the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's a consequence of Darboux theorem, according to which the derivative $f'$ of a differentiable function $f:I\to \Bbb R$ has the intermediate value property (IVP). Since a real-valued function $g$ defined on some interval $J$ is a homeomorphism onto its image if and only if it is injective and it has the IVP, your $f'$ will be continuous.